# Android: Layout keeps moving up and down when putting in Text in EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm new to android development, and I think I messed up somewhere with the XML. Attached is the relevant code. What happens is when I try to enter in text into the EditText, the editText keeps shifting up and down as I try to type into it. It's lagging my phone, and I suspect I made a mistake with the layout.

I tried to use LinearLayout setup vertically and horizontally for a cleaner format than relative, and I think it the problem is with the weight, but I've been fiddling with the values for weight and I can't seem to figure this out.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/summoner1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/champSpinner1"
        android:entries="@array/champions"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:entries="@array/positions"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/summoner2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/champSpinner2"

        android:entries="@array/champions"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:entries="@array/positions"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/summoner3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/champSpinner3"

        android:entries="@array/champions"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"

        android:entries="@array/positions"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/summoner4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/champSpinner4"
        android:entries="@array/champions"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:entries="@array/positions"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dodge?"

    android:id="@+id/checkButton"
    android:onClick="onClickDodge"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: This line `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` makes your containers fit their children height.

Comment: Is this the problem? I know it fits the height of what is in the EditText, but it  even when I start typing, it keeps moving. Additionally, it only does this with the last EditText (4th one, bottommost)

It does freak out when I edit any of the editTexts though?

So would you suggest having a number there instead of wrap_content?

Comment: Better. But I'd redesign the layout to be as flat as possible. Possibly, I'd use a ListView to contain my rows.

Comment: Try with relative layout , rather than linear.